# foreach loop to copy file into all directories in c:\users\ ... hopefully a simple one

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

Aim: I need to copy and paste Teams backgrunds into all users profiles on lots of machines
Error: Path does not exist.
I can't figure out the issue why my path  C:\users\user1\Appdata turns into C:\Users1 Users2\Appdata

Here is the full code:

```
$Folders = Get-ChildItem -Directory "C:\Users"   | Where-Object {$_.Name -notlike "Public"}  | Where-Object {$_.Name -notlike "AppData"}
$Backgrounds = "\\Server1\Teams-Backgrounds\*"



Foreach($Folder in $Folders) {

Copy-Item -Path $Backgrounds -Destination "C:\Users\$($Folders.Name)\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Teams\Backgrounds\Uploads" -Force -ErrorAction Stop

}
```

Comment: `$($Folders.Name)` is meant to be `$($Folder.Name)`. You are trying to do it on the entire collection instead of the single object in the foreach loop.

Comment: Yep... One of those moments where you say to yourself  "It's been a long day".

Comment: A tip is never to use plurals of your collection in loops. E.G. `Foreach($Item in $Folders)` or `Foreach($Dir in $Folders)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you are after.

```
# Combined the Where-Object filter into a single
$Folders = Get-ChildItem -Directory "C:\Users" | Where-Object {($_.Name -notlike "Public") -and ($_.Name -notlike "AppData")}
$Backgrounds = "\\Server1\Teams-Backgrounds\*"

Foreach($Folder in $Folders) {
    # Changed $Folders.Name to $Folder.Name
    Copy-Item -Path $Backgrounds -Destination "C:\Users\$($Folder.Name)\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Teams\Backgrounds\Uploads" -Force -ErrorAction Stop
}
```